# Access style of selected element on click

Tags: d3.js

Given the following markup:

```
<a href="#" class="foo" style="display: block">Bar</a>
```

When I click *Bar* on the page, I'm expecting this code:

```
d3.select(".foo").on("click", () => {
  console.log(this.style.display);
);
```

to give the output: *block*.

However, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo Furtado. Seems, there is a difference between `() => {}` and `function() {}`.

Comment: Yes, there is a huge difference between regarding `this`. Just use a regular function or, alternatively, the third and second arguments combined, as in the dupe targets.